# How to get a list of possible template candidates in Silverstripe 4?

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

Developing SilverStripe 4 projects I have found it somewhat complicated to get a list of all the possible candidates for a given override.

So my question:

How can I get a full list of possible template candidates for a given page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in a controller you can call the method `getViewerTemplates` on either the controller itself or the `DataRecord` as `getViewerTemplates` is a method on `ViewableData`.

```
$this->dataRecord->getViewerTemplates();
$this->dataRecord->getViewerTemplates($action); //If you're calling an action
$this->getViewerTemplates(); //If you don't have a datarecord
```

All that actually is, is an implementation of the [`get_templates_by_class`](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/4/src/View/SSViewer.php#L308) method on `SSViewer`.
I think it will return what you need.